# How to imlement "warnings" with HTTP protocol?

Tags: http, network-protocols

My server application provides a special URL `/myapp/status` for internal monitoring. If the application is Ok it returns an HTTP response with code `200 (Ok)`, otherwise it returns a response with code `503 (service unavailable)`.

Now I would like to add a "warning" case ("I am not ok but still available"). I would like my application to return a response with code 200 and reason "warning" in this case.

Does it make sense? Can I send a "reason" along with code `200`?

Comment: Is the HTTP status code the only signaling method allowed? You CAN create your own http codes, eg. `200` = everything 100% ok, `201` = only mostly ok, `202` = "hanging in there", `203` = "mostly dead" and so on.

Comment: @MarcB 202, 202, 203, and 204 codes are reserved. I hope I can use any code > 204.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep true to the HTTP semantics, continue to return a `200 OK` code, but add `Warning:` headers to the response (those are defined as per [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.46)).